# static function cannot reference with this keword in java

Tags: java

car.java

```
package com.krishna;

public class car {
    private int door;
    private int wheels;
    private String model;
    private String engine;
    private String colour;

    public void setModel(String model)
    {
        String validModel=model.toLowerCase();
        if(validModel=="krish"||validModel=="raju")
        {
            this.model = model;
        }
        else
        {
            this.model="unknown";
        }
    }

    public static String getModel()
    {
        return this.model;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.krishna;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        car obj1=new car();
        car obj2=new car();
        obj1.setModel("krish");
        System.out.println(obj1.getModel());
    }
}
```

static function cannot reference with this keword in java

Comment: first of all, ask yourself: what object is `this` in `getModel()` method? And what object is `this` in `setModel()`? Hint: `getModel()` has `static` modifier, whilst `setModel()` hasn't.

Comment: Not really what you asked but `if(validModel=="krish"||validModel=="raju")` ->
 [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also there is no `this` in static context. `static` means that member (method here) belongs to entire class, not specific instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods belong to the class not objects of that class. Remove `static` keyword from  `static String getModel()` for this to work.